# Issues in my code for form validation, when the user submits the form

Tags: jquery

I have written the code  for jquery validation when the user submit the form.I have some issue in my code

**issue**:

1. if name field is null.it shows the error message.if user enter the values in textfield also still  error message is displaying.
2. further I want to know how to validate the field? if all the text fields is null in my code.(where to put if condition).then form has to go action.php.
3. guide me if there is better way to do also.

Here is the html form:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Jquery Validation</title>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/thk.js.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="jsqval" action="action.php" method="post">
    <table width="56%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" align="center">

  <tr>
    <td>Name:<input type="text" name="usernmae" value="" id="name" /><br><span id="names" style="color:#F00;"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>E-Mail Id:<input type="text" name="email" value="" id="email" /><br><span id="emails" style="color:#F00;"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Country Code:
        <select name="cuntry" id="ctry">
        <option value="">----country code----</option>
        <option value="1">Ind(+91)</option>
        <option value="2">AUS(+88)</option>
        <option value="3">RSA(+77)</option>
        <option value="4">ENG(+66)</option>
        </select>
        <span id="countrys" style="color:#F00;"></span>
        &nbsp;
        <input type="text" name="phone" value="" id="phon" /><span id="phones" style="color:#F00;"></span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tuition:<input type="text" name="tuition" value="" id="tuition" /><span id="tuitions" style="color:#F00;"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Class Location:<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="myhome"  value="My Home">My Home
        <input type="checkbox" name="TutorHome"  value="Tutor's Home">Tutor's Home
        <input type="checkbox" name="institute"  value="Institute or Coaching Center">Institute or Coaching Center
        <input type="checkbox" name="online"  value="Online Class">Online Class
        <span id="check" style="color:#F00;"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Pincode: <input type="text" name="tuition" value="" id="tuition" /><span id="tuitions" style="color:#F00;"></span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        a=$('#name');
        if(a.val()=='')
        {
            $('#names').html("Please Enter Your Name");
            a.focus();
            return false;
        } 

        b=$('#email');
        if(b.val()=='')
        {
            $('#emails').html('Please enter your e-mail Address');
            b.focus();
            return false;
        } 

        resg=$('#ctry');
        if(resg.val()=='')
        {
            $('#countrys').html("Please Select your country name");
            resg.focus();
            return false;
        }
        d=$('#phon')
        if(d.val()=='')
        {
            $('#phones').html("Please Enter your phone number");
            d.focus();
            return false;
        }
        asd=$('#tuition');
        if(asd.val()=='')
        {
            $('#tuitions').html("Please Enter your tuition");
            asd.focus();
            return false;   
        }

         y = false;
             $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
                 if (this.checked) 
                 {
                 y = true;
                 }

                if (y==false) 
                {
                  $('#check').html("Please Check me");

                }
                return false;
             });


    });

});
```

Comment: can you make a codepen for this.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I don't want to use plugin how does time to complete the simple form I have already done that.some issue in field validation.stack is a big team can any come forward give the possible answer for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use some existing scripts like [1](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) to validate the form at browser level. There are plenty of them available, written in jquery. Hope this helps.

**[Reference](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)**

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I don't want to use plugin how does time to complete the simple form I have already done that.some issue in that.stack is a big team can any come forward give the possible answer for me.

Comment: really I want to know the error in the form.I don't like to use the existing plugin.lot is available no need for that.that to small functionality. if you can help me out with these scenario.It is great help for me. mainly i want to know how to fix the issue boss